# enumerate command producing differents alignments

Tags: align, enumerate

(I´m sorry by my poor English)
I´m using the enumerate command. But it produces differents alignments. As we see below. Why does it happen? I would like to use the first case but as to align on the second case. Is it possible? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{myheadings} \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item $\displaystyle f(x) = x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x$
        \item $\displaystyle f(x) = xe^{-2x}$
        \item $\displaystyle f(x) = e^{-x} - e^{-2x}$
        \item $\displaystyle f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2 - x^3}$
        \item $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^3}{1 + x^2}$
        \item $\displaystyle f(x) = x \ln x$
        \item $\displaystyle f(x)=xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$.
        \item $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}$.
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[(a)] $\displaystyle f(x) = x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x$
        \item[(b)] $\displaystyle f(x) = xe^{-2x}$
        \item[(c)] $\displaystyle f(x) = e^{-x} - e^{-2x}$
        \item[(d)] $\displaystyle f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2 - x^3}$
        \item[(e)] $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^3}{1 + x^2}$
        \item[(f)] $\displaystyle f(x) = x \ln x$
        \item[(g)] $\displaystyle f(x)=xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$.
        \item[(h)] $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}$.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumitem`, with  option `[shortlabels]` in the place of enumerate. With the key `before=\everymath{displaystyle}`, you won't have to type `displaystyle` for every formula of every item. Also, preferably, use the `utf8` input encoding, whichh is the default for all modern editors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{myheadings} \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{enumerate}[(a), before = \everymath{\displaystyle}]
        \item $ f(x) = x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x$
        \item $ f(x) = xe^{-2x}$
        \item $ f(x) = e^{-x} - e^{-2x}$
        \item $ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2 - x^3}$
        \item $ f(x) = \frac{x^3}{1 + x^2}$
        \item $ f(x) = x \ln x$
        \item $ f(x)=xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$.
        \item $ f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}$.
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[(a)] $\displaystyle f(x) = x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x$
        \item[(b)] $\displaystyle f(x) = xe^{-2x}$
        \item[(c)] $\displaystyle f(x) = e^{-x} - e^{-2x}$
        \item[(d)] $\displaystyle f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^2 - x^3}$
        \item[(e)] $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^3}{1 + x^2}$
        \item[(f)] $\displaystyle f(x) = x \ln x$
        \item[(g)] $\displaystyle f(x)=xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$.
        \item[(h)] $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2-1}$.
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]